# Navigate from one page to another in reactjs using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router

Hi i am new to reactjs and trying to navigate from one page to another by clicking on a link using react router. I am having a home.js in which there is a list of some places name, i want to click on one of the name so that it should move on to its details page i.e about.js.
I tried the below mentioned code so far but its not working, by clicking on the link i cannot navigate to the about page. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my home.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import data from './data.json';
import {Link, BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import About from './about.js'


 export var rows = data.map((row) => 
     <Router>
      <div className="Display-items">
        <li> <Link to="/about" onClick={handleClick.bind(this,row)} target="_blank">{row.name}</Link > &nbsp; &nbsp;  {row.price} &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src = {row.image} height="50" width="50" alt="Preview"/></li>
        <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
      </div>
     </Router>
      );


 function handleClick(row,e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(row.name, 'was clicked');
  }



 export function RenderList(rows){
      return(
        <div>
          <li> Name &nbsp; &nbsp; Price &nbsp; &nbsp; Picture </li>
          {rows}
        </div>
      ); 
   }
```

And this is my about.js

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';

 class About extends Component{
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <h2>Hello!</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
 export default About;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several problems with your implementation, first try to get out the `Router` component from your `map` and write your RenderList like so :

```
export function RenderList(rows){

    return(
      <div>
      <li> Name &nbsp; &nbsp; Price &nbsp; &nbsp; Picture </li>
      <Router basename={props.path}>
        <div>
          <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        </div> 
      </Router>
       {rows}
      </div>
    ); 

}
```

React router don't accept more than one children, so instead of creating A router for each Route you can just use one single Router and wrap all your Routes inside of it with a `div` surrounding them.

Next step, your `map` should look like this :

```
export var rows = data.map((row) =>
    <div className="Display-items">
      <li> <Link to="/about" onClick={handleClick.bind(this, row)} target="_blank">{row.name}</Link > &nbsp; &nbsp;  {row.price} &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src={row.image} height="50" width="50" alt="Preview" /></li>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I have only created a single router enclosed in <div> and why my router has to be out from my map?